# Force open link in new background tab (Android firefox)

Tags: android, firefox

Goal: From a website having a lot of links, I will usually middle click the ones I want. Firefox will open them in background new tabs on the side. Now I want to do the same from my Android tablet where middle click is not available.

1) Best: Is there an easy way to middle click on a tablet ?
2) Otherwise something better than a long press to simulate right click then open in new tab ?

3) I'm currently trying a TamperMonkey solution based on other questions found here:

```js
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event){event.preventDefault();return newBackgroundTab(this);}, false);

function newBackgroundTab(node) {
    var newWindow = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
    newWindow.blur();
    window.focus();
    newWindow.location.href = node.href;
    return false;
}
```

It also need to set the **dom.disable_window_flip** option to false in Firefox.

This works on desktop, but not on Android, focus stays on the new tab even though the disable option was already on false by default.